# Sort by filter is not visible in Webpage in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am new to Joomla community. In product category in virtuemart, I have setup sorting fields like sort the products by Alphabetically manner, new and old products.I have written php code in default.php. But dropdown is not visible over the webpage. Below is the code of PHP.

```
<span class="category-order-by" id="custom-category-order-by">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="custom_orderby"><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDERBY') ?></label>
                      <select class="form-control select-picker" id="custom_orderby" name="custom_orderby" onchange="document.location.replace(this.value);">
                        <option disabled selected>Select an option</option> 
                        <option <?php if(strpos($url,'/by,product_sales?keyword=') !== false) {?> selected <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $urlPath ?>/by,product_sales?keyword=">Best Selling</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </span>
```

Comment: Maybe you'd like to join the [joomla.se] Stack Exchange community.  Posting your Joomla questions there gains the attention of volunteers that are specifically knowledgeable regarding Joomla and associated software.  Why is there a comma in your url string -- that seems odd to me.  Why is `keyword` not assigned a value?  The first `<option>` never needs a selected attribute; if no other option is selected, it is the default.

Comment: Is the whole default.php not being displayed? Or just a piece of it?

Comment: @mickmackusa only just piece of it.

Comment: So other elements from the same file are being printed to screen?  We need to know more about your issue.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, other elements are getting printed. Only sort by filter is not visible.